# Icecast: pause in the beginning of streaming on Android

Tags: android, icecast, internet-radio, liquidsoap

I have a server Icecast working with Liquidsoap to stream internet radio and I noticed there is a problem with receiving the music on some Android devices (Samsung Galaxy tab, for example) - after a few seconds of buffering of the music the playing of the music starts for about a second, then it abruptly stops, then there is a silence for a few more seconds, and only after that it starts playing normally. On some other Android devices, like HTC desire - no such thing occurs - music starts playing normally after the bufferization.
Here is the example of the stream in question: http://rdsradio.ru:8000/4th.mp3

That happens when I open the link in the browser (Google Chrome) on the Android device. With the same result I connected to the Icecast stream from the Android app, which I currently develop, using the android.media.MediaPlayer class: `mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://rdsradio.ru:8000/4th.mp3");`

Also, even on those problem devices I could normally connect and listen the streams of other Icecast radio sources, like http://dancewave.hopto.org:9990/dance.mp3 
- that is why I think there could be something wrong in my settings of Icecast + Liquidsoap - what makes that music stops playing in the beginning.

```
<burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
<burst-size>64000</burst-size>
```

I tried to change those parameters in /etc/icecast2/icecast.xml, like increasing the burst-size to 10-20 times or setting burst-on-connect to 0, but did not notice any difference at all (I run `/etc/init.d/icecast2 reload` after changing the parameters to reload the configuration).

Any idea - how to fix that behavior?

UPDATED: I tried to open the stream in VLC player on Android and it worked with no problem, so it seems the problem in using the android.media.MediaPlayer (probably the built-in HTML5 audio player in Google Chrome uses the same library). I will try to use a different Media Player in the app.

Comment: Which player are you using on Android? You don't seem to specify that.

Comment: @TBR added the note to the post. Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the solution was simple. The burst-size setting to 500000 in icecast.xml fixed the problem. Earlier I used `/etc/init.d/icecast2 reload` after changing the icecast.xml and for some reason I thought that the burst-size would also change in Icecast in the similar way, but it didn't happen. Only restart of icecast actually changed that setting.

Comment: we've same problem, we'll test with your suggestion. What's the <queue-size> and <burst-size> value that you0ve used?

Comment: @Francesco <queue-size>600000</queue-size>, 
<burst-size>500000</burst-size>